# removeClass of a DIV created in the same function

Tags: jquery, function

I want to remove a class of a DIV element that is created as soon as a function is called.

The thing is that I want to have the `.removeClass` also be part of that function.

**This is the function I have now.**

```
function user_message(msg) {
  var html = '<div class="user-reply FadeElement" style="display: flex;">'+
  msg.text + '</div>';
  return html;
}
```

I have tried adding the `.removeClass` function inside the `user_message` function

```
function user_message(msg) {
      var html = '<div class="user-reply FadeElement" style="display: flex;">'+
      msg.text + '</div>';
      return html;
      $('.user-reply').removeClass('FadeElement');
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Perhaps I can add the `$('.user-reply').removeClass('FadeElement');` everywhere the `user_message` function is called, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it inside the function

**The `user_message` function is called like this.**

```
$("#user-window").append(user_message( value ));
```

Comment: How does `function user_message(msg)` gets called ? you write code for remove after that code .

Comment: Why can't you just take FadeElement out of the html?  `var html = '<div class="user-reply" style=...`?

Comment: @Swati updated the info with the requested details $("#user-window").append(user_message( value ));

Comment: @RichN, because I have a fadein class that need to be executed only one per div, and I am .appending the function DIV to another DIV

Comment: As, you already got answer ..other way would be putting that code after append line i.e : `$('.user-reply:last').removeClass('FadeElement');`

Comment: Just tried, but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it wont work because you are returning the result before even removing the class.

Second, you can add a timeout (if that might resolve your issue):

```js
function user_message(msg) {
    var html = '<div class="user-reply FadeElement" style="display: flex;">'+
    msg.text + '</div>';
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.user-reply').removeClass('FadeElement');
    },1000);
    return html;
}
```

Comment: That did it. I actually tried removing it before the `return html` but `$('.user-reply').removeClass('FadeElement');` was indeed executing fractions before appending the DIV. The setTimeout did the trick.